# posting a javascript array as a an array of JSON objects

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am posting to a rails controller an array of json objects via a jQuery ajax request. Do I need to use JSON.stringify or should jQuery handle it for me?

```
  var vals = [{"name":"item name #1"},{"name":"item name #2"}];
  $.ajax({
    url: '/arc/api/v1/calculate_items',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {line_items: vals},
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(r){
```

vs

```
  var vals = [{"name":"item name #1"},{"name":"item name #2"}];
  $.ajax({
    url: '/arc/api/v1/calculate_items',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {line_items: JSON.stringify(vals)},
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(r){
```

Comment: Did you check both ways? which one worked for you?

Comment: using JSON.stringify seemed to work but would like to hear something more definitive.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to use JSON.stringify?

You need to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to first [`serialize`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your object(or an array of objects) to JSON, and then specify the content-type so your server understands it's JSON.

> jQuery handle it for me?

No, it is not.

There are two jQuery method which does it automaticly,  [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), [`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.getJSON("/some/url", function(data) { 
   // the data is already a plain JSON object
})


var data = /* Your data in JSON format - see below */;
$.post("/some/url", data, function(returnedData) {
  // the returnedData is already a plain JSON object    
})
```